# Compare same value in 2 different lists - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm very new to kotlin and I'm doing this exercise where you need 2 lists, one for the invoice and another for the invoice values, for example:

**Invoice**..........................│  **Invoice Values** 
invoiceNumber = 1........│  itemName = Pepsi 
customerName = Alfred│  quantity = 2 
TotalValue = $13,00......│  price = 2.50 
......................................│  invoiceNumber = 1 
......................................│ 
......................................│  itemName = Cereal 
......................................│  quantity = 2 
......................................│  price = 4 
......................................│  invoiceNumber = 1

and I got it to show only the invoiceNumber that I want, but I can't manage to get the results to do "total += quantity*price" here is what I tried so far:

```
fun main() {

  
    data class VarInvoice(val numInvoice: Int, val dateInvoice: String, val ssn: String, val total: Double)
    
    data class VarItem(val nameItem: String, val quantity: Int, val unitPrice: Double, val numInvoice2: Int)

    val invoice= mutableListOf(
            VarInvoice(1, "25/05/1990", "84739572857", 0.00),
            VarInvoice(2, "02/09/2009", "38295840284", 0.00),
            VarInvoice(3, "13/07/2020", "74959572857", 0.00)
    )

    val invoiceItem = mutableListOf(
            VarItem("Pepsi", 2, 2.50, 1),
            VarItem("Cereal", 2, 4.00, 1),
            VarItem("Coke", 4, 3.5, 2),
            VarItem("Chicken", 1, 13.50, 3)
    )

    val itemInvoice = invoiceItem.groupBy(VarItem::numInvoice2)
    val invoiceEqual = itemInvoice.getValue(1)
    println(invoiceEqual)

    //but this returns me: [VarItem(nameItem=Pepsi, quantity=2, unitPrice=2.5, numInvoice2=1), VarItem(nameItem=Cereal, quantity=2, unitPrice=4.0, numInvoice2=1)]
    //and i have no idea how to do like: if invoiceNumber2 == invoiceNumber { (total += price * quantity)}
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do. Are you totaling the cost of everything on each specific invoice, or on a specific invoice? Why are there two invoices with the same `numInvoice`?

Comment: Your code seems to include quite a bit of irrelevancy, but is missing important stuff.  Where are `invoiceNumber` and `invoiceNumber2` to be defined?  (Are they local variables, or fields of one of your classes?)  And what connects a `VarInvoice` (which seems to hold the `total` you want to update) with a `VarItem` (which holds the `unitPrice` and `quantity` I'm guessing you want to update it from)?

Comment: I have 2 "numInvoices" because its not always that "invoiceItem"s "numInvoice" is equal to the "invoice". The numInvoice in "invoice" is unique, but "invoiceItem" can have more than 1 item for the same "numInvoice" i hope you understand, this got confusing. I'm trying to get the total of the "invoice" list to be total += price * quantity of the item

Comment: @gidds I was going to hardcode `invoiceNumber` and `invoiceNumber2`, I don't know how to connect the `VarInvoice` to `varItem` to update the total :(

Answer (score 0):

### Map to total

Assuming you are trying to get the total of a invoice, here is something you could do:

```kotlin
    val totals = invoiceItem.groupBy { it.numInvoice2 }.mapValues { item ->
        item.value.sumByDouble { it.unitPrice * it.quantity }
    }
```

The `totals` is a map of invoice number to the total price of all associated items. (assuming you are trying to join `invoice` to `invoiceItem` on `invoiceNumber2 = invoiceNumber`

### Extension Property

Or you can slap an extension property onto the VarInvoice, instead of declaring it on the data class as a property (just beware that you can't do this in a function (e.g. your main function))

```kotlin
val VarInvoice.total get() = invoiceItem
        .filter { it.numInvoice2 == numInvoice }
        .sumByDouble { it.unitPrice * it.quantity }
```

It would be nice you can provide more information on how you are going to build your application. There could be better solution to this.

### P.S. 1

> after your code, I got: `{1=13.0, 2=14.0, 3=13.5}` and I'm trying to figure a way of it beeing sorted and to include the ssn of the person, like this: `{1=13.0 "by person with ssn: "84739572857, 3=13.5 "by person with ssn: "74959572857, 2=14.0 "by person with ssn: "38295840284` Sorry, english is not my main language and I can't thank you enough!

Technically you can try something like this:

```kotlin
    val totaledInvoice = invoiceItem.groupBy { it.numInvoice2 }.mapValues { item ->
        invoice.first { it.numInvoice == item.value.first().numInvoice2 }.copy(
                total = item.value.sumByDouble { it.unitPrice * it.quantity }
        )
    }
```

You can return whatever you want in the `mapValues` lambda, but the code is getting ridiculous and inefficient. I would suggest trying out the extension property solution.

Comment: It was exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much! You are the best. I'm still having a bit of trouble trying to understand what sumByDouble does, is it similar to a `+=`?.
If I may ask, is there any way I could make it prettier? Like ordering from lowest total to highest, inserting the name of the `ssn` of the person, etc

Comment: @ThrowawayToLearn Not quite. `sumBy` doesn't add value to an existing number, rather, it returns you a new number, which is the sum. To sort stuff, you can use the `sortBy`. If you want to add a name property to the `VarInvoice`, you need to add that declaration to the data class.

Comment: sorry I didn't meant the name, i mean the string `ssn` on the `invoice` list.
Thank you for everything!

Comment: @ThrowawayToLearn Do you mean changing the value of the `ssn`? You can do that if you change the `val` to `var`. `val` means the variable is not mutable.

Comment: after your code, I got: `{1=13.0, 2=14.0, 3=13.5}` and I'm trying to figure a way of it beeing sorted and to include the `ssn` of the person, like this: `{1=13.0 "by person with ssn: "84739572857, 3=13.5 "by person with ssn: "74959572857, 2=14.0 "by person with ssn: "38295840284`
Sorry, english is not my main language and I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @ThrowawayToLearn I added a response in the answer. Actually do you have to do all these in a function? If no you can create a new class deal with this more efficiently.